# Bootstrap 5 select data-live-search not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5 and I try to add live search to a form select.
In Bootstrap 3 I can just do it like following:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
   <option>A</option>
   <option>B</option>
   <option>C</option>
</select>
```

I have tried the same for bootstrap 5 but it does not work.
After some research I have found the datalist, where I can search:

```
<input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" placeholder="Type to search...">
<datalist id="datalistOptions">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</datalist>
```

The live search works but it is not the same.

Is there any way to make it just like in bootstrap 3?

Thank you very much!